# Why does the decoration of windows eliminate in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 12.04, compiz

I am using my computer, do some work, use the chat, game, which any person does, but, of nothing I realize that the decoration of windows disappears, which leaves me without being able to conceal, maximize, minimize and close the windows. I use Ubuntu 11.10 of 64 bits, and have installed compiz config.

I use unity.

Comment: can you please provide more details?,window decorations disabled after playing with compiz config settings manager?

Comment: Had same bug here. Happens sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

This tends to happen with Compiz, I have found. Whenever this happens to me, my entire top panel disappears.

Whenever this happens, you can remedy it by running terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and typing

`unity --replace`

If terminal won't launch, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and run the same command after you enter your username and password. After you run `unity --replace`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to your desktop.

Comment: Finally `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-panel` did not work for me. And using `Ctrl+Alt+F1 & F7` is pretty clever, that way you are not logged out. So I vote to remove my answer and vote for yours